# Asimov story about an astronaut stranded on a strange planet who accidentally clones himself

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov

I read the story many years ago and tried to find it again but I can remember very little of it.

- It was about an astronaut who landed on a planet and couldn't return to earth.
- A voice was talking to him telling him how to survive and would explain to him how to create another human. He eventually cloned himself by accident and he starts to think about how to recreate his spaceship too...

Unfortunately I don't remember much more but hopefully somebody out there will know which one it is...

Comment: To some, "many years ago" might be 10 years ago, to others it might be 60. Could you narrow it down to a decade or two?

Comment: Is it a novel or a short story? How sure are you that Isaac Asimov was the author?

Comment: Sounds like the Red Dwarf episode "Rimmerworld".